# FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. How do I debug the code or what changes should I make to resolve this firebase error

Tags: firebase

```
 


 
      
    const imgUrls = await Promise.all(
      [...images].map((image) => storeImage(image))
    ).catch(() => {
      toast.error("Images not uploaded");
      return;
    });
    console.log(imgUrls);

    // Save form data
    const formDataCopy = {
      type,
      name,
      bedrooms,
      bathrooms,
      parking,
      furnished,
      address,
      offer,
      regularPrice,
      discountedPrice,
      imgUrls,
      location: address,
      timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    };

    if (!offer) {
      delete formDataCopy.discountedPrice;
    }

    try {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "listings"), formDataCopy);
      console.log(docRef);
      toast.success("Listing Created!");
      navigate(`/Category/${formDataCopy.type}/${docRef.id}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      toast.error("Error creating the listing");
    }

  };
```

**FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field imgUrls in document listings/prpqVwUrvwxDw6ADpl57)
**

I am facing this problem every time I am creating the listing.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.